# Deploying spacy model to Elastic using eland

Tags: elasticsearch, spacy, huggingface-transformers, eland

I'm trying to ingest a spacy model (scispacy abbreviations detector to be specific), but I'm struggling with the deployment.

I have deployed many models using eland but spacy models do not contain the config.json file and eland complains about that.

Is there a way to generate this config.json file, os tweak eland to accept spacy models?

Found some scispacy based models but none of them have the config.json file:

https://huggingface.co/thet-system/en_core_sci_md
https://huggingface.co/surrey-nlp/en_abbreviation_detection_roberta_lar

No idea where to start.

Thanks